# Missing the iPhone "Installed Apps" tab in iTunes on Mac

Tags: ios, itunes, mac

iTunes use to allow me to see the apps installed on my connected iPhone. I could see the screens and rearrange them. But its missing now. Where did that section go?

I am using iTunes 12.7.0.166 on my Mac running High Sierra with my iPhone running iOS 11.0.1

Answer (score 1):

With iTunes 12.7 Apple has [removed app management from iTunes](https://www.macrumors.com/2017/09/12/apple-itunes-12-7-no-app-store/)